# Bug in sorting of questions

Tags: bug, sorting

I normally got to the questions tab, select my favourite tag `C`, and look at all the active questions. I suddenly noticed one day that there was a `java` question, with no `C` tag, appearing in that list. I made sure that I had selected my tag, and yes I had. You can see an image:

[image]

I also check the web link which was: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c

I do not understand how this happened. Can some of the developers fix this bug?

**NOTE:** After refreshing the page once, the result did not go. After refreshing it twice it went. But why did it not go the first time?

Comment: The real bug here is a [c] tag on a Java question.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably caching.

That question [used to have](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35595645/1) the [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) tag, which [was removed in a later revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35595645/2). The search query still had that question ID cached in its results.

Comment: Yes it had the `C` tag, but after I refreshed, it was still there, and again refreshing lead to removal of the question.

Comment: So, the query that gets all questions tagged with [tag:c]. Then a question has the tag removed, but the query still has the result cached, with that question in there.